# DataFrameを作った際、indexの並びを固定化したい

Tags: python, python3, pandas

Dataframeでデータを作成し、そのデータをそのままcsvに出力をしようとした際、
indexで指定した並び順(column)ではなく、アルファベット順になって出力されてしまいます。
indexで指定した並び順のままにするにはどうすれば良いのでしょうか？

記述内容としては以下のような内容です。

```
import pandas as pd

def create_csv():
    df = pd.DataFrame([])
    data = [[0, "are", "sore"],[1,"kore","dore"]]

    for i in range(len(data)):
        add = pd.Series(data[i], index=["key", "data1", "data2"])
        df = df.append(add, ignore_index=True)

    print(df)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    create_csv()
```

上記の結果としては以下の内容が表示されています。

```
  data1 data2  key
0   are  sore  0.0
1  kore  dore  1.0
```

なのですが、表示させたい内容としては、
indexで指定した順番で以下のように表示を行いたい、というものです。

```
  key data1 data2
0 0.0   are  sore
1 1.0  kore  dore
```

Comment: おそらく `pandas.to_csv()` メソッドなどを利用されているかと思いますが、casga さんが実行されたコードや、差支えがなければデータの一部を質問欄に追記していただけますか？

Comment: 応答が遅くなりましてすみません。
やりたい内容を踏まえて記述イメージを記載してみました。

Comment: 一行づつ append するのではなく、data とカラム名を指定してデータフレームを作成する事ができます。`pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["key", "data1", "data2"])`

Comment: なぜかDataFrameには都度appendしないといけないと思いこんでいたようでした。ありがとうございます！

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DataFrame`の列の順番が変わっても、次のようにすればすぐに元に戻せます。

```
df = df[["key", "data1", "data2"]]
```

`df.append`の所で列の順番が変わっているので、次のようにすれば列の順番は変わらなくなります。

```
def create_csv():
    df = pd.DataFrame([], colums=["key", "data1", "data2"])
    data = [[0, "are", "sore"],[1,"kore","dore"]]

    for i in range(len(data)):
        add = pd.Series(data[i], index=["key", "data1", "data2"])
        df = df.append(add, ignore_index=True)
```

また、コメントにあるように、配列から直接DataFrameを作成する方が簡単です。

```
def create_csv():
    data = [[0, "are", "sore"],[1,"kore","dore"]]
    df = pd.DataFrame(data, colums=["key", "data1", "data2"])
```

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。そもそもDataFrameに突っ込めば良いという考えに至らず発生していたのと、DataFrameの定義の際にcolumsで設定しておけば変わらなくなるのが理解できました。コメントありがとうございました！